# Error SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

tengo un problema con una consulta en sql, yo  cree un procedimiento almacenado, en el cual hago una consulta para traer varios datos, pero tengo que hacerlo hacia 26 BD distintas, el error esta en que tengo una tabla temporal para hacer la insercion de los datos de las 26 BD y a la hora de ejecutar el procedimiento me sale el siguiente error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

y al clickear el error me señala especificamente esta linea,[image: Error]

Este es el Codigo del Procedimiento, Agradeceria si alguien me orienta con que puede estar pasando, (aca solo estoy buscando solo en 1 BD)

```
exec Informe_Cartera_PRUE '2019','01','26'
USE [Porcisoft_Cliente_PDV0]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Informe_Cartera_PV]    Script Date: 27/02/2019 06:30:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Informe_Cartera_PRUE] @Year  NVARCHAR(4), 
                                             @Month NVARCHAR(2),
                                             @Day   NVARCHAR(2)
AS 
     SET NOCOUNT ON; 
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Cartera]
     ([codigo]        [CHAR](30)      NULL, 
      [Codbodega]     [CHAR](30)      NULL,
      [NombreCliente] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,
      [Consecutivo]   [CHAR](20)      NULL, 
      [Fecha]         [DATETIME]      NULL, 
      [Fechavence]    [DATETIME]      NULL, 
      [codtipodcto]   [NVARCHAR](5)   NULL,
      [Totalgeneral]  [NUMERIC](20,2) NULL,
      [Saldo]  [NUMERIC](20,2) NULL,       
     )
     ON [PRIMARY];

--Apartado
INSERT INTO #Cartera
SELECT FA0.Codigo,
    FA0.Codbodega,
    RTRIM (FA0.nombre )+' '+ RTRIM(FA0.Nombre1) +' '+RTRIM( FA0.Apellido)+' '+RTRIM(FA0.Apellido1) AS NombreCliente,
    FA0.Consecutivo,
    FA0.Fecha,
    FA0.Fechavence,
    FA0.codtipodcto,
    FA0.Totalgeneral,
    (FA0.Totalgeneral-((IsNull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)))) as Saldo
FROM (
        SELECT S0.Nombre,
            S0.Nombre1,
            S0.Apellido,
            S0.Apellido1,
            S0.Telefono1,
            S0.EsCliente,
            S0.EsEmpleado,
            F0.tiporeferencia,
            F0.Codigo,
            F0.consecutivo,
            F0.Referencia,
            F0.Fecha,
            F0.Fechavence,
            F0.codtipodcto,
            F0.Totalgeneral,
            F0.codbodega
        FROM PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencfacturas F0 
        INNER JOIN tblsocio_negocios S0 ON F0.codigo=S0.codigo
        WHERE F0.Fecha <= @Year+'/'+@Month+'/'+@Day+'23:59') AS FA0 
        LEFT JOIN ( 
                    SELECT A1.codtipodcto,
                        A0.Codigo,
                        A1.Factura,
                        SUM(A1.Valor)AS Valor,
                        SUM(A1.Retencion)AS Retencion
                    FROM PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencabonosfactura A0 
                    INNER JOIN tblmvtoabonosfactura A1 ON A0.documento=A1.documento
                    WHERE A0.Fecha<=@Year+'/'+@Month+'/'+@Day+'23:59'
                    GROUP BY  A1.codtipodcto,A0.Codigo,A1.Factura) AB0 ON FA0.consecutivo = AB0.factura 
                                                                      AND FA0.codtipodcto = AB0.codtipodcto
        WHERE (FA0.Totalgeneral-((IsNull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)))) > 1 
           OR (FA0.Totalgeneral-((IsNull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)))) < -1 
           AND FA0.tiporeferencia <> 'FAP' 
           AND FA0.codtipodcto <> 'FAP' 
ORDER BY Codbodega ASC, nombrecliente ASC;

SELECT * FROM #Cartera
```

Comment: Eso que marcas, no parece ser la linea 20...

Comment: ya pude solucionar esa parte, pero ahora, me dice esto: 
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Hay algun problema en una conversion. no se que mas te podemos decir, sin saber algo de las db o sus formatos.

Answer (score 1):

Con un poco de formato, es mucho más fácil encontrar el error. Tienes la siguiente concatenación que luego comparas con una columna datetime.

```
@Year+'/'+@Month+'/'+@Day+'23:59'
```

A esa cadena le falta un espacio entre el día y la hora para poder ser convertida correctamente.

Mi recomendación es que envíes directamente una fecha o al menos utilices el formato ISO-8601 (YYYYMMDD o YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss.mss).
Si cambias tus tres parámetros a uno solo tipo `DATE` la comparación queda de la siguiente manera

```
WHERE A0.Fecha < DATEADD( DD, 1, @ParametroDate)
```

Así eliminas el riesgo de perder filas que puedan ocurrir en el último minuto del día.

Answer (score 1):

Con un poco de formato, es mucho más fácil encontrar el error. Tienes la siguiente concatenación que luego comparas con una columna datetime.

@Year+'/'+@Month+'/'+@Day+'23:59'
A esa cadena le falta un espacio entre el día y la hora para poder ser convertida correctamente.

Mi recomendación es que envíes directamente una fecha o al menos utilices el formato ISO-8601 (YYYYMMDD o YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss.mss). Si cambias tus tres parámetros a uno solo tipo DATE la comparación queda de la siguiente manera

WHERE A0.Fecha < DATEADD( DD, 1, @ParametroDate)
Así eliminas el riesgo de perder filas que puedan ocurrir en el último minuto del día.